# Passing int between scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have to pass int for one script to other one, but its not just one script that is in one GameObject. This script is on three GameObjects (three weapons, and that script have his ammo etc), and the shoot script is on the camera (because I want to shoot in the middle of the screen).

Script on the Camera

```
void Update () 
{
    //Si preta el click izquierdo se ejecuta shoot()
    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        shoot();
    }
}

//Le vamos a pasar la variable de la municion, para que solo pueda disparar si le queda
public void shoot(int ammoCargador)
{
    RaycastHit hit;

    //Raycast desde la camara, hacia delante, la informacion del raycast y con el rango que le demos
    if (Physics.Raycast(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, range)) 
    {
        Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);

        //A quien hemos impactado (), y lo llamamos target
        EnemyBase target = hit.transform.GetComponent<EnemyBase>();

        //Comprobamos si lo que hemos impactado es un enemigo
        if(target !=null)
        {
            //Si lo es le mandamos la variable de daño
            target.TakeDamage(damage);
        }
    }
```

Script on the weapons

```
public int ammoCargador= 10, ammoCargadorMax, ammoMochila, ammoMochilaMax;
//Ponemos el GameObject Camara porque es el que lleva el script que nos permite disparar
public GameObject Camara;

private void Start() 
{
    //Le asignamos que camara se llama Main Camera
    Camara = GameObject.Find("Main Camera");
}

void Update () 
{
    WeaponShoot Mandar = Camara.transform.GetComponent<WeaponShoot>();
    Mandar.shoot(ammoCargador);
}
```

I get the error on the camera script, in `shoot();` inside the update

(There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter)

Comment: On the script attached to your camera, you're doing this `if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")){
        shoot();
    }` but the `shoot` function requires int as arg. Maybe something like this `shoot(4)`?

Comment: Now it has not error, but if in shoot() i try to print ammoCargador   it only shows 4 if i click, and if i dont click it prints 0 all the time

Comment: Like I said, you have to pass an `int` to the `shoot` function. The code I provided above that uses 4 is just an example. You can pass any number to it

Comment: Thats what im trying to do, pass int ammoCargador of the weapons script, and check all the time if it changes

Comment: You find the weapon's object `GameObject weapon = GameObject.Find("WeaponGameObject");` then get the script component `Weapon weapon = weapon.GetComponent<Weapon>();` then get the `ammoCargador` var from it and use it `shoot(weapon.ammoCargador)`

Comment: So i have to do this three times? Because there is three differents weapons

Comment: With the-same weapon script but different GameObject name?

Comment: yeah, Using the same script on the weapons, but each one will have different ammount of ammo, damage etc

Comment: You haven't described what you're doing. You want to each all three weapons at the-same time?

Comment: I think you architecture is not quite good because whom will shoot is the weapon and you just need the camera for raycast projection, so why don't you put all your shooting logic on weapon script and just uses the camera script to return the GO that raycast hits and you resolve your logic locally on weapon?

Comment: I did it and much better yeah, im so bad. Sorry for invonvenients

Answer (score -1):

`public void shoot(int ammoCargadora)` means that you have to pass in an argument of type int when calling the method, which you aren't doing here:

```
if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")){
    shoot(); //should be "shoot(123);" or some other number.
}
```

if you want, you can make the parameter optional by changing that line to `public void shoot(int ammoCargadora = 123)`, where 123 is your default Value.

Comment: Not the downvoter but isn't this the-same thing I mentioned in the comment section but OP is still having problems with? Looks like he's trying to pass another variable from another script to that function

Comment: Unrelated: you just edited a question and turned a screenshot into text ("transcribed image cause OP was too lazy to post code") . Long story short: dont do that. chances are that you introduce a typo. When a user posts code as image, the "correct" solutions are: A) give a comment telling him to not do that B) downvote ... close vote. A) you can do by now (welcome to comment level), for B+C you will need some more reputation ;-) ... hope that makes sense. Feel free to drop me a comment, then I will remove my comment here.

Comment: And well: you did exactly that: your "text" version of the code in the image did contain a typo.